# Remove the filename of an url with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I had in my blog urls like these:

```
www.miblog.com/post-name/1.html
www.miblog.com/post-name-two/2.html
www.miblog.com/other-post/3.html
```

I have changed the permalinks to

```
www.miblog.com/post-name/
www.miblog.com/post-name-two/
www.miblog.com/other-post/
```

I want to put a 301 redirection from the olds url to the news url. Can I do this with htaccess?

The blog runs with Wordpress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code **on top of all other rules**:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/[^.]+\.html$ $1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```